# Error creating mysql table using php

Tags: php, mysql

`$createtable=mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(username VARCHAR(20),password VARCHAR(20),read TINYINT(1),write TINYINT(1),search TINYINT(1))");`

I get the following error when trying to create the table using the above query:
Error creating user table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read TINYINT(1),write TINYINT(1),search TINYINT(1))' at line 1

how do i successfully create the table?thanks in advance.

Comment: `read` is a mysql reserved word, so you'd need to wrap it in backticks to get it working (ditto for `write`). You should look at changing the field names if at all possible instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 $createtable=mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(username VARCHAR(20),password VARCHAR(20),`read` TINYINT(1),`write` TINYINT(1),search TINYINT(1))");
```

you have `read` and `write` are mysql reserved keywords , so you should around them by backticks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$createtable=mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(`username` VARCHAR(20),`password` VARCHAR(20),`read` TINYINT(1),`write` TINYINT(1),`search` TINYINT(1))");
```

Comment: While this will work, it's generally bad practice to use reserved words as column names.

Comment: should be ``write`` [reserved-words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html)